# How to set a multiple OnClickListeners in Android

Tags: java, android

How to set a multiple `OnCLickListener` in Android?

If I try to do it by using `setOnClickListener`, only the last one get called:

```
button.setOnClickListener(l1);
button.setOnClickListener(l2);
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Please see: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)

Comment: I translated it for you, but please use en on this site

Comment: Each button can only have one click listener.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to take a good look at your code and refactor it to avoid needing to do this.

But if you must, I would call both of the actions you're wanting to trigger within one implementation.

Like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Overrride
    public void onClick(View view){
        actionOne();
        actionTwo();
    }
});
```